# gltf, are matrices ever to be transposed?

Tags: c++, animation, matrix, graphics, gltf

As I am learning gltf, I already have 2 working skin models, and now I am trying the RiggedFigure.

The 2 other models worked just fine and I am using the same code. I am using the vscode gltf extension to verify my output.

The documentation states:

> Accessors of matrix type have data stored in column-major order; start of each column must be aligned to 4-byte boundaries.

Eigen matrices are also column major, thus copying the raw bytes into an stl vector of type `Eigen::Matrix4f` should result in the correct data, and indeed, this is the case for 2 of the 3 models I have tried so far.

However for the rigged figure, vs code says the matrices should be (excuse the screenshot but I cannot copy paste the matrices for some reason):

[image]

My code prints:

```
     0.999983 0.000442018  0.00581419 -0.00398856
          0    0.997123  -0.0758045   0.0520021
  -0.005831   0.0758032    0.997106   -0.684015
          0           0           0           1

         1          0          0          0
         0   -0.01376   0.999905   -0.85674
         0  -0.999905 -0.0137601   0.024791
         0          0          0          1

        1         0         0         0
        0  0.979842  0.199774 -0.224555
        0 -0.199774  0.979842  -1.05133
        0         0         0         1

          1           0           0           0
          0 -0.00751853    0.999972    -1.12647
          0   -0.999972 -0.00751847  0.00796944
          0           0           0           1

          -1 -1.50995e-07            0            0
           0   0.00364935     0.999993     -1.19299
-1.51869e-07     0.999993  -0.00364941   0.00535393
           0            0            0            1

 -0.0623881    0.998036 -0.00569177  0.00162297
   0.891518   0.0531644   -0.449853    0.404156
  -0.448667  -0.0331397   -0.893084    0.998987
          0           0           0           1

 0.109672  0.988876 -0.100484  0.107683
-0.891521 0.0531632 -0.449849  0.404152
-0.439503   0.13892  0.887434 -0.993169
        0         0         0         1

 0.530194  0.847874  0.001751 -0.183428
 0.760039 -0.474352 -0.444218  0.206564
-0.375811  0.236853 -0.895917  0.973213
        0         0         0         1

-0.0705104  -0.619322   0.781965  -0.761146
 -0.760038  -0.474352  -0.444223   0.206569
  0.646043  -0.625645  -0.437261   0.633599
         0          0          0          1

   0.631434    0.775418 -0.00419003   -0.228155
   0.649284    -0.53166   -0.543845    0.154659
  -0.423935    0.340682   -0.839175    0.951451
          0           0           0           1

 0.111378 -0.773831  0.623523 -0.550204
-0.649284 -0.531661 -0.543845   0.15466
 0.752347 -0.344271 -0.561651  0.809067
        0         0         0         1

  -0.830471   -0.549474    0.091635 -0.00030848
  0.0339727   -0.214148    -0.97621    0.596867
   0.556025   -0.807601    0.196511   -0.159297
          0           0           0           1

 -0.994689   0.102198  0.0121981 -0.0750653
-0.0339737  -0.214147   -0.97621   0.596867
-0.0971548   -0.97144   0.216482  -0.140501
         0          0          0          1

    -0.99973    0.0232223 -7.82996e-05    0.0784336
   0.0051282     0.217484     -0.97605     0.357951
  -0.0226493    -0.975788    -0.217544    0.0222206
           0            0            0            1

  -0.998171  -0.0599068 -0.00810355  -0.0775425
-0.00512856    0.217484    -0.97605    0.357951
  0.0602345   -0.974224   -0.217393   0.0251548
          0           0           0           1

 -0.999327  0.0366897          0  0.0783684
 0.0287104   0.781987   0.622632 -0.0567413
 0.0228442   0.622213  -0.782514  0.0634761
         0          0          0          1

 -0.999326 0.00828946  0.0357652 -0.0814984
 0.0287402   0.782804   0.621604 -0.0521458
-0.0228444   0.622213  -0.782514  0.0634761
         0          0          0          1

   0.994013    0.109264 0.000418345  -0.0755577
   0.109252   -0.993835  -0.0188101  -0.0405796
-0.00164008   0.0187438   -0.999822   0.0227357
          0           0           0           1

   0.994011   -0.109281 0.000483894   0.0755372
  -0.109253   -0.993836   -0.018811  -0.0405797
 0.00253636   0.0186453   -0.999823   0.0228038
          0           0           0           1
```

Which are the transposed versions of what vs code says.

My loading code is this (instantiated with typoe `Eigen::Matrix4f`):

```cpp
    void CopySparseBuffer(
        void* dest,
        const void* src,
        const size_t element_count,
        const size_t stride,
        const size_t type_size)
    {
        assert(stride >= type_size);
        // Typecast src and dest addresses to (char *)
        unsigned char* csrc = (unsigned char*)src;
        unsigned char* cdest = (unsigned char*)dest;
        // Iterate over the total number of elements to copy
        for(int i = 0; i < element_count; i++)
            // Copy each byte of the element. Since the stride could be different from the
            // type size (in the case of padding bytes for example) the right access
            // should skip over any interleaved data, that's why we use the stride.
            for(int j = 0; j < type_size; j++)
                *(cdest + i * type_size + j) = *(csrc + i * stride + j);
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T> ExtractDataFromAccessor(
        const tinygltf::Model& model, const int accessor_index, bool print = false)
    {
        const int buffer_view_index = model.accessors[accessor_index].bufferView;
        const int array_type = model.accessors[accessor_index].type;
        const int component_type = model.accessors[accessor_index].componentType;
        const int accessor_offset = model.accessors[accessor_index].byteOffset;
        const int element_num = model.accessors[accessor_index].count;
    
        const int buffer_index = model.bufferViews[buffer_view_index].buffer;
        const int buffer_length = model.bufferViews[buffer_view_index].byteLength;
        const int buffer_offset = model.bufferViews[buffer_view_index].byteOffset;
        const int buffer_stride = model.bufferViews[buffer_view_index].byteStride;
    
        const std::vector<unsigned char> data = model.buffers[buffer_index].data;
    
        assert(
            component_type == ComponentCode<T>() &&
            "The component type found here should match that of the type (e.g. float and "
            "float).");
        assert(array_type == TypeCode<T>());
        // Size in bytes of a single element (e.g. 12 for a vec3 of floats)
        const int type_size = sizeof(T);
        assert(
            buffer_stride == 0 || buffer_stride >= sizeof(T) &&
            "It doesn't make sense for a positive buffer "
            "stride to be less than the type size");
        assert(element_num * type_size <= buffer_length);
        const size_t stride = std::max(buffer_stride, type_size);
    
        std::vector<T> holder(element_num);
        CopySparseBuffer(
            holder.data(),
            data.data() + buffer_offset + accessor_offset,
            element_num,
            stride,
            type_size);
    
        return holder;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out so i will leave this here in case someone is in the same situation in the future.

The VS code vectors are the columns, not the rows, so my code and vs code actually agree, it's just the vs code output is confusing.

In short, evrything works, the output is just confusing.

Comment: That sounds like a bug.  Can you file it?  Thanks!  https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-vscode/issues

Comment: https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-vscode/issues/199